# Android | issue in creating new project in android 2.1.2 and 2.1.3

Tags: android

i'm kinda new in android development, so i'll explain what's happen to my as.
i have a big issue in android studio, and when i installed android studio in my win 10 everything installed very clear and complete but when i'm click on Next in Configure your new project, after i entered info nothing gonna happen.
i tried to install another win and also with 2.1.3 but still same thing is happening.

[image]
after all i tried to just open main app by importing app from templates in startup app, and when gradle downloaded and more stuff in continue, still there's more problems in app.

[image]

and sry for bad english btw. 
i really need help on this.
tnx and best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In company domain change it to something like:

```
yourname.com
```

if you leave it example it won't let you continue :)

Comment: well, tnx for answer dude, but still same problem is happening.

Comment: If you're still having issues, i'd do a full uninstall and a full reinstall. It's possible your installer got corrupted or a file it wrote got corrupted. And while installing make sure it has admin permissions. If you run into the same issue after, let me know!

Comment: i'll try to reinstall it again. but honestly it's now more than 10 times i'm unistalling and installing. but not in this os i just installed. so i'll try it again. btw i just started app and it's say No adroid sdk found... LoL...

Comment: i download my android studio with full sdk from original site. do u think dat might be from installer with sdk or not?

Comment: well huge tnx mate. i just did everything from first.
Install > Config SDK > Change example.com to another domain > and Done.